# Subgroup generated by all elements with odd order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the set of elements with odd order in $G$, we will denote this set as $S$.

Prove that $H$ is normal in $G$ and that $G/ H$ is a group of order $2^n$.

My attempt:

Since $H$ is generated by $S$, $H$ is normal in $G$ $\iff$ $gsg^{-1} \in H \space \forall s\in S$.

and that's where I'm stuck, I cant find the way the use the property of the elements with odd order.

regarding the second part, since $|G| = |G:H|\cdot|H|$ we have to show that $\frac {|G|}{|H|} = 2^n$.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean $G/H$ is a group of order $2^n$, right? $G \setminus H$ means $G$ minus the elements of $H$)

Comment: As far as I can see, of the three answers at the indicated earlier question, only the one by Nicky Hekster answers the second part correctly.